# Cannot add record(s); join key of table not in recordset in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm new to access, and I have been able to find a solution for most of the hiccups I have experienced with MS Access, but I cannot get a combo box in a form to function properly.

I have tried unbounding it, but then it does not update the corresponding field in the query the form is based on. I have tried to bound it to the EmployeeID, but then cannot select the Employee in the combo box because EmployeeID is an autonumber field.

If anyone can offer me any advice on how to get this to function properly, it would be greatly appreciated. Also, the basic intent of the form is to allow an employee to select their name, enter a date, and check the appropriate boxes. All of the other values function properly, but I do not want the Employee table to change every time a maintenance log is created weekly...

I hope I explained everything well enough. Attached below is a copy of the database.

[Maintenance Log Database](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-h0XCD7IRuoVmdxZWw5N0dYM2c/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up the combo box with a row source that contains both the Employee ID and the Employee Name. Use Employee ID as the bound column. Then in the display properties set columns to 2 and column widths to 0;1 (assuming you set your row source so that Employee ID is column 1 and Name is column 2).

This way your combo box displays the name but it actually binds to and uses the ID.

Comment: This allows for the drop-down menu, but I am still unable to select anything, as it says "join key of table 'tblWeeklyResults' not in recordset."

Comment: You have to add your Employees table to the query that feeds your form and set up the relationships so that it always includes the Employees but only the records that match from the rest of the tables.

Comment: Also a general tip: Never use spaces in the names of fields/tables/queries/forms. It will cause you numerous headaches later.